# Woocommerce products outputting error code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

> 'Notice: product_type was called incorrectly . 
>   
> Product properties
>   should not be accessed directly. Backtrace:
>   require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php'),
>   wc_get_template_part, load_template,
>   require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php'),
>   do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart, wc_get_template,
>   include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php'),
>   apply_filters('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link'),
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, {closure},
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.0.) in
>   /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01ax/b534/ipg.gamemergecom/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4138'

I have recently encountered this error after fixing an internal server error with my website and I am stuck on going about fixing it.

This message displays under every product added to the site.

Comment: What fix actually you did?

Comment: I increased the PHP memory limit.

Comment: This is a common problem for code that hasn't been updated to work with WooCommerce 3.0. See the linked duplicate.